# How to alter SVG-element on a web-page with contebnt from a new file?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I use SVGInject to load svg-images inline:

`<img src="image1.svg" id="changeme" onload="SVGInject(this)" />`

This works like a charm, and the image can be moved, rotated etc.
But is it possible to later "change" the image maybe?

document.getElementById('changeme').src = 'image2.svg';
SVGInject(document.getElementById('changeme'));

This does NOT work.
Should the object be reloaded? Or the original destroyed and a new created...

cheers

Comment: setting imgElem.src = 'newUrl' should work - what's the function doing exactly, are you using a framework?

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks for the suggestion. The issue has not got anything to do with a framework, the reason is apparently the way SVGInject() works, when it is injecting svg-content into the IMG-object.

Comment: ah yes, so it's not the framework but the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the svg won't work as svg-inject.js removes the original img element.
Thus, `document.getElementById('changeme')` can't select or replace anything.

You might wrap the original `SVGInject(el)` function in a helper function that's cloning the img element before inlining svg.
This way you can replace the img src, remove the previously inlined svg and finally re-inject the changed svg url.

```js
/// find and replace all svgs with class name "svg-replace"
var svgInjects = document.querySelectorAll('.svg-replace');
if(svgInjects.length){
    for(var i=0; i<svgInjects.length; i++){
        var svgEl = svgInjects[i];
        // modified inject function
        SVGInjectCloned(svgEl); 
    }
}
  
  
function SVGInjectCloned(svgEl){
    var svgCloned = svgEl.cloneNode(true);
    svgEl.parentNode.appendChild(svgCloned);
    
    /// hide original 
    svgEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

    // inline svg
    SVGInject(svgCloned);
    //console.log('svg inlined');
}


function replaceSvg(previousSvgEl, newSvgUrl){
    var svgEl = document.querySelector(previousSvgEl);

    // find and delete previously inlined svg
    var inlinedSvg = svgEl.nextElementSibling;
    if(inlinedSvg){
        inlinedSvg.remove();

        /// make original visible again
        svgEl.removeAttribute('style');

        // update svg src
        svgEl.src = newSvgUrl;

        // reclone svg element for inlining
        var svgCloned = svgEl.cloneNode(true);
        svgEl.parentNode.appendChild(svgCloned);

        /// hide original 
        svgEl.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
        SVGInject(svgCloned);
    }   
}
  
  
// example button
var newSvgUrl =
"data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='user-friends' class='svg-inline--fa fa-user-friends fa-w-20' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 640 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='currentColor' d='M192 256c61.9 0 112-50.1 112-112S253.9 32 192 32 80 82.1 80 144s50.1 112 112 112zm76.8 32h-8.3c-20.8 10-43.9 16-68.5 16s-47.6-6-68.5-16h-8.3C51.6 288 0 339.6 0 403.2V432c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h288c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-28.8c0-63.6-51.6-115.2-115.2-115.2zM480 256c53 0 96-43 96-96s-43-96-96-96-96 43-96 96 43 96 96 96zm48 32h-3.8c-13.9 4.8-28.6 8-44.2 8s-30.3-3.2-44.2-8H432c-20.4 0-39.2 5.9-55.7 15.4 24.4 26.3 39.7 61.2 39.7 99.8v38.4c0 2.2-.5 4.3-.6 6.4H592c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48 0-61.9-50.1-112-112-112z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E";

var btnSvgReplace = document.querySelector('.btnSvgReplace');
if(btnSvgReplace){
btnSvgReplace.addEventListener('click', function(){
    replaceSvg('#firstSvg', 
    newSvgUrl
    );
});
}
```

```css
 img,
 svg
 {
 width:100px;
 height:100px; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@iconfu/svg-inject@1.2.3/dist/svg-inject.min.js"></script>

<div class="svg-wrp">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='users' class='svg-inline--fa fa-users fa-w-20' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 640 512'%3E%3Cpath fill='currentColor' d='M96 224c35.3 0 64-28.7 64-64s-28.7-64-64-64-64 28.7-64 64 28.7 64 64 64zm448 0c35.3 0 64-28.7 64-64s-28.7-64-64-64-64 28.7-64 64 28.7 64 64 64zm32 32h-64c-17.6 0-33.5 7.1-45.1 18.6 40.3 22.1 68.9 62 75.1 109.4h66c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32v-32c0-35.3-28.7-64-64-64zm-256 0c61.9 0 112-50.1 112-112S381.9 32 320 32 208 82.1 208 144s50.1 112 112 112zm76.8 32h-8.3c-20.8 10-43.9 16-68.5 16s-47.6-6-68.5-16h-8.3C179.6 288 128 339.6 128 403.2V432c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h288c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48v-28.8c0-63.6-51.6-115.2-115.2-115.2zm-223.7-13.4C161.5 263.1 145.6 256 128 256H64c-35.3 0-64 28.7-64 64v32c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h65.9c6.3-47.4 34.9-87.3 75.2-109.4z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E" class="svg-replace" id="firstSvg" />
  </div>  
<p><button class="btnSvgReplace">Replace svg</button></p>
```

Comment: THAT makes a lot of sense!
Thanks for a very elaborate answer and code example.
You are a champ...!

Comment: @HansOttoLunde If the answer solved the problem, it's best you click on the checkmark next to it. This not only marks it as solved, but also gives some points to the one giving the helping answer